# Set gridview backcolor to color from datatable?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a `datatable` that looks like this:

```
Row1       Row2    Row3    Row4    Row5    Row6
Gold       Gold              
Pink       Pink              
#FB7703    #FB7703               
Red        Red               
Yellow                       
Green                        
#0B93E1                      
Purple
```

This is what the grid looks like when When I bind the datatable to the grid:
[image]

How can set background color of the cells in the gridview to the color in the cell?

I know I need to use `RowDataBound`.

Markup for gridview:

```
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridViewClicks" runat="server" 
        onrowdatabound="GridViewClicks_RowDataBound">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

And codebehind that fills datatable:

```
DataTable dataTable = GetColors();

DataTable gridTable = new DataTable();
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row1", typeof(string));
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row2", typeof(string));
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row3", typeof(string));
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row4", typeof(string));
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row5", typeof(string));
gridTable.Columns.Add("Row6", typeof(string));

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    var r = gridTable.NewRow();
    gridTable.Rows.Add(r);
}

foreach (DataRow r in dataTable.Rows)
{
    int rowNum = Convert.ToInt16(r[1]) - 1;
    int colNum = Convert.ToInt16(r[3]);
    gridTable.Rows[rowNum][colNum] = r["color"].ToString();
}

GridViewClicks.DataSource = gridTable;
GridViewClicks.DataBind();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please let me know why my question was downvoted so that I can improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the value of each cell in the `RowDataBound` event and color the cell based on it's value.

```
protected void GridViewClicks_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the current row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //loop all the cells in the row
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            //check if the color is hex or a string
            if (cell.Text.Contains("#"))
            {
                cell.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(cell.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                cell.BackColor = Color.FromName(cell.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```