# Change table row text and bgcolor on a listview value asp.net C

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview and I am trying to change the text color and background color depending on the value of "callswaiting". This is written in C#.

I am trying to accomplish this:

```
  If(Eval("availableAgents") < 1); Then
; If(Eval("callsWaiting" > 2) ,Then );
{    
    tblSheet.Style.Add("color", "black");
    tblSheet.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
}
    Else;
{
    tblSheet.Style.Add("color", "black");
    tblSheet.Style.Add("background-color", "orange");
}
    End If;
Else;
{
    tblSheet.Style.Add("color", "white");
    tblSheet.Style.Add("background-color", "green");
}
    End If;
```

Just stumped on how to update this to ASPX and C#.

My ASPX code is:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
        </Triggers>            
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="con_csq_agentDB" onitemdatabound="ListView1_ItemDataBound">
                     <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="MainTableRow" style="background-color: #ADADAD;">
                            <td style="background-color: gray; color: whitesmoke;">
                                 <asp:Label ID="csqnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("csqname") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="callswaitingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("callswaiting") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="convoldestcontactLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("convoldestcontact") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="loggedinagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("loggedinagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="availableagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("availableagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="talkingagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("talkingagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                     <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr id="MainTableRow" style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000;">
                            <td style="background-color: gray; color: whitesmoke;">
                                 <asp:Label ID="csqnameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("csqname") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="callswaitingLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("callswaiting") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="convoldestcontactLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("convoldestcontact") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="loggedinagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("loggedinagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="availableagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("availableagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <asp:Label ID="talkingagentsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("talkingagents") %>' />
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                     <LayoutTemplate>
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" data-height='100%'>
                            <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #113C77; color: #000000;">
                                             <th runat="server"></th>
                                             <th runat="server">Calls waiting</th>
                                             <th runat="server">Current Wait</th>
                                             <th runat="server">Agents Logged in</th>
                                             <th runat="server">Ready</th>
                                             <th runat="server">Talking</th>
                                         </tr>
                                         <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                                         </tr>
                                     </table>
                     </LayoutTemplate>
```

My C# code is:

```
public partial class csq_agent : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListView1.DataSourceID = con_csq_agentDB.UniqueID;

            }
}
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataitem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;
    int callswaiting = (int)DataBinder.Eval(dataitem.DataItem, "callswaiting");
    if (callswaiting == 3)
    {
        HtmlTableRow cell = (HtmlTableRow)e.Item.FindControl("MainTableRow");

        cell.BgColor = "Red";
    }

}

}
```

Comment: And your question is what exactly?

Comment: What is the best way to do this? I have been reading others but, only see examples for gridview or listview while it is written in VB only. I am very new to coding.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239923/set-gridview-backcolor-to-color-from-datatable/43240144#43240144), it has some of the basics you would need. Second a `ListView` does not have a row property, so you either need a GridView or make a method that colors a `div` or `tr`

Comment: Okay, Thank you! I will check it out and change to a GridView. I read that ListView was more customizable and that is why I went with ListView.