# How to iterate over GridView rows using Linq

Tags: asp.net, linq

How can I iterate through grid rows using Linq?

I want to change row color on basis of column value.

Comment: Any code to show your failed attempt? Took a look at this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set gridview backcolor to color from datatable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239923/set-gridview-backcolor-to-color-from-datatable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use following code

```
GridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(r => (r.Cells[0].Value != null && r.Cells[0].Value.ToString().ToLower().Equals("nonveg"))).ToList().ForEach(c => c.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red);
```