# Is it possible to change grid color in asp.net using particular column value from database

Tags: asp.net, gridview, c#-4.0

I have one particular column value in the database, which has different values, As I want to change the color of grid in asp.net, based on each value. I don't want to hard code the column value

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: ok, how can it be done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239923/set-gridview-backcolor-to-color-from-datatable/43240144

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assume a table like this:

[image]

Ok, so that is a table. I suppose the column could be in the same as our table that drives the grid view, but the process works the same.

Ok, so now our markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And our code to load the grid:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Dim strSQL As String =
        "SELECT tblHotels.ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, tblHotels.City, Province, Description, Color from tblHotels
        LEFT JOIN tblCityColor on tblCityColor.City = tblHotels.City
        ORDER BY HotelName"

    Using cmdSQL As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strSQL, New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))

        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        Dim rstTable As New DataTable
        rstTable.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        GridView1.DataSource = rstTable
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using

End Sub
```

The above loads our grid. But for formatting colors? We joined in that above "color" table into the query.

So, now in the row data bound event, we can do this:

```
Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        If IsDBNull(gData.Item("Color")) = False Then
            e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = FromName(gData.Item("Color"))
            e.Row.Cells(5).BackColor = FromName(gData.Item("Color"))
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Not that for defaulted gv columns, or databound, the columns appear in the cells array as per above.

Output:

[image]

Now it is possible you have some (or all) templated fields in the gv.

You then don't use cells collection, but have to use find control.

So say our grid has this markup:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"       />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"     />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"               />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Province" HeaderText="Province"       />

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescript" runat="server" 
                            Text = '<%# Eval("Description") %>' >
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

So for above, to change the description (which is a plane jane text box). then the code to format background color would be:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim gData As DataRowView = e.Row.DataItem
        If IsDBNull(gData.Item("Color")) = False Then
            e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = FromName(gData.Item("Color"))

            Dim txtDesc As TextBox = e.Row.FindControl("txtDescript")
            txtDesc.BackColor = FromName(gData.Item("Color"))
        End If

    End If
```

Comment: Thank You, Albert, for the response, I want to color grid-based column condition I don't want to store color in a separate table and load it into the grid.

Comment: Sure, no problem - I mean that color table "join" only creates (gives) us a extra handy dandy plane jane column for the condition. If you have a column already in the given query/table, then use that column - the code above will be much the same.  It not clear what condition you want to use? I mean, you can even hard code in a few colors right into the row data bound event if you want. But either way - it quite much the same code approach.  So, whatever condition you want to use I see no issue.